# How to use one time domain name in android?

Tags: android, url, dns

I have a `RESTful web-service`, I am retrieving a data to android device

So here My `ip address`/`Doamin` name may change like..
`192.168.0.1` or`1-255` etc or It may be `www.stackexchange.com` or `www.stackoverflow.com`

Like my data will be stored in `192.168.0.1/rst/api/login` or `www.stackoverflow.com/rest/api/sitemview`

So to over come this I want to use domain name as One time when i install application

in my application I have other pages like `Login`,`display list-view`, `Single ItemView`.

So this domain name should stored in device and pass to other activities every time when I use.

I used shared preferences like

```
public static void savePreferences(Context ctx, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

so when they load

```
public static Object loadSavedPreferences(Context ctx, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
}
```

So here My problem is that This one time value is not permanent when ever I force close or Restart devise that passing value is not working

Any suggetion

Comment: So your domain name is not passing after restart I think its stored as temp or cache...

Comment: yes sir any suggestion for that...

Answer (score 0):

If your domain name fixed, use below code.

```
public class WS{
   public static final String domain="http://blah.ws";
}
```

Access it in each activity
with

```
String apiPath=WS.domain+your_rest_path;
```